Find movie please
I have watched this movie before but I don’t remember what’s it called. It’s about a girl who was home alone, on the phone with her mom. Later she get raped. The girl then moves to a different town. 
When she gets settled in she takes pictures of her neighbors houses. She later on sees a women arguing with a man outside. They were arguing about the woman’s daughter. When it becomes night the same woman gets killed. 
The girl tries to figure out who killed the women. The girl predicts that a guy that makes a lot of noise did because the woman always calls the cops on the guy because of the loud noise. Turns out the daughter was the one that killed her. 
Side note: the girl ends up liking the guy that made the loud noise.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

What do you mean by the guy that makes a lot of loud noise? Like, with his mouth? Plays loud music? Builds things in his garage? Has a loud car? Like, what?

Sounds like "Stalked by my Neighbor" 
Here's a description of some the scenes you mentioned from a reviewer:

"The movie starts with teenage photographer Jodi (Kelcie Stranahan of Last Hours in Suburbia) talking to her mom Andrea (Amy Pietz of Deadly Spa) on Skype (or whatever lame imitation this movie uses). The mom's working late, but she left Chinese food in the fridge, because she's cool like that. She's also cool for ordering that fancy camera lens for Jodi. She tells her to go check the mail and see if it's there. Too bad there's a scary guy waiting right outside the door. He gets into their condo and attacks Jodi, all while her mom is watching on the computer. We find out later she was raped. Yeah… Pretty heavy stuff for a movie with this literal a title...   
...What a surprise, then, when the next day Jodi sits in her window
  taking photos of her neighbors across the street. The movie never
  explains why she does this, but I guess we're just supposed to assume
  every weird thing she does is because of her past trauma. She's
  wearing shoes on her hands? Past trauma. She's watching The Big Bang
  Theory? Past trauma. In this case, she captures an argument between
  two of her neighbors that will be important later. So it's not just
  because of the past trauma; it's also for the sake of plot
  convenience."

Preview: 


